# Orientation is not working for UITableview inside AlertView

Tags: iphone, uiview, orientation, uialertview

i have created Custome AlertView Class by inheriting UIAlertView
and i added UITableView in the 
-(void)prepare

method

[image: This is Image of TableView inside UIAlertView with Potrait Orientation]

[image: This is when i Changed Orientation]

can any one Suggest me the way to get out of this problem...
Thanks in Advance.

i have done this to keep track of Orientation change

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    NSNotificationCenter* notifCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notifCenter addObserver:self
                    selector:@selector(orientationChanged)
                        name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                      object:nil];
```

Comment: are you giving any Autoresizing property for Tableview ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a nice idea for control, I found the Git repository with a ready one: https://github.com/blommegard/SBTableAlert/blob/master/SBTableAlert.m

It has the orientation change logic scheduling `layout` method on orientation change with a zero interval. The code is distributed under copy-free MIT license so you can either use it or just take some useful tips.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and I will check it and get back to you soon.